# Какие есть способы и инструменты для парсинга различный токенов?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно спарсить некоторые значения типа: authority_token, signature, oauth_token и.т.п.

Проделываю через http запросы авторизацию ТикТок.
Некоторые значения я могу найти в запросах Get. Но некоторые, вроде значения signature, генерируются в процессе отправки запроса, то есть этот ключ (signature), уникален на каждый отправленный запрос и больше не повторяется.
Я так понимаю он генерируется на стороне клиента через js. Нашел вроде этот js который генерирует но он совсем не понятен, там около 800 строк с однобуквенными переменными. Возможно, я так понимаю он меняется после компиляции в вот таке вот месиво из переменных и операторов.
В связи с этим вопрос - какие есть варианты парсить подобные значения? Если ты не знаешь как долго живет этот токен, каким образом он используется и как проверяется и главное как он генерируется.

Для проверки я брал куки которые получил через браузер и ставил лайк на видео без этой сигнатуры. Проверил ответ который я отправлял пост запросом и через браузер - они были идентичны. Но почему то при отправки пост запроса лайк не ставился, хотя ответ был положительным. И тут 2 вопрос, почему так может происходить? понимаю что возможно информации не так много, но хотя бы предположения какие-нибудь.

Comment: Как именно посылаете Post-запрос? Используете HttpClient? Хедеры тоже сравнивали с теми, которые в браузере? User-Agent задан?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, только его оболочку Xnet. Хедеры сравниваю с теми, что отправляет браузер и мой пост запрос. Юзер агент конечно задаю - рандомный

Comment: предполагаю, что все таки сигнатура проверяется сервером, и или алгоритмы тик тока понимают, что был отправлен запрос в ручную, а не через браузер. Еще возможно дело в TLS

Comment: Если дело в TLS, у вас должен быть текст ошибки установки TLS соединения. Но если к примеру у вас Windows 8+ и .NET Framework 4.6+/Core 3.1/5, то проблема точно не в TLS. .NET Core и .NET 5 даже HTTP/2 поддерживают. Вас ждут достаточно невеселые часы отладки в браузере, всякие токены из ниоткуда не берутся.